Why the data batch size for loop failing for Insert API in python Django?
We are using 3rd party API to pull data and enabled pagination, hence the amount of data coming in are huge. Some times 12000 records at a time in a list.

We are using mySQL DB, and it fails when it receives that amount of
data at a time. So, as temporary solution I wanted to implement the
"batch size" concept as below:
batch_size = 3
    for batch in range(0, len(payload), batch_size):
     batch_data = payload[batch:batch + batch_size]



Below is the POST method code snippet where we are getting the data source and its format , and how I am passing it.
def post(self, request):
    data = fetch_data.get(request=request)

    try:
        if data.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
            payload = data.data
            payload["token_id"] = token_id
            payload["org"] = org

            api_log(
                msg=f"TOtal cont data from xyz : {json.dumps(payload)}"
            )

            api_log(
                msg=f"Size of cont data from xyz : {len(json.dumps(payload))}"
            )

            api_log(
                msg=f"Length of cont data to db: {len(payload)}"
            )

            api_log(
                msg=f"Total cont data to DB: {payload}"
            )

            url = ("http://example.com")


            batch_size = 3
            api_log(msg=f"[BATCH SIZE]:: {batch_size}")
            for batch in range(0, len(payload), batch_size):
                api_log(msg=f"[BATCH SIZE]:: {batch_size}")
                api_log(msg=f"[BATCH]:: {batch}")
                batch_data = payload[batch:batch + batch_size]
                api_log(msg=f"[BATCH DATA]:: {batch_data}")

                response_data = requests.post(
                    url,
                    json=batch_data,
                )

            if response_data.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED:
                api_log(
                    msg="data inserted successfully"
                )
                return Response(
                    {"message": "API Info completed successfully"}
                )

            else:
                return Response(
                    {"error": "Failed to send data "},
                    status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                )

My problem is when I am implementing the batch size concept it is failing with 500 error as seen below:
Exception for module : API failed with status code 500

However, if I remove that batch size logic, the data goes in to requests.post() and I get success message.
In my dev environment we have less data, may be less that 100 records. So, the "page size" I have taken is 20, especially for this, as it has total 50 row counts in the data source as I could check in my postman.
So, again, I have taken page size as 20, so I will get 3 pages(20, 20, 10), and the batch size I have taken 3.
Below is the sample JSON request.
{
    "xyz": [
        {
            "id": "45435345",
            "r_id": "sdgvrtrvrt",
            "name": "Furniture"
        }
    ],
    "r_data": [
        {
            "Name": "Furniture",
            "Phones": 5123523
        }
    ]
}

Please suggest. Thank you
